# Sending Unicode string from C# to C++ working in one project but not another

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unicode, pinvoke

I have built a test harness solution with two projects in VS2017, a C# project where I am sending a unicode string and a C++ DLL where I receive it and show it in a MessageBox.

My C# code is:

```
[DllImport(@"TestDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern void SendString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str);

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SendString("Test2 String ☻我是美国人");
    }
```

My C++ code is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall SendString(wchar_t *IncomingPath)
{
    MessageBoxW(
        NULL,
        IncomingPath,
        L"Header",
        MB_ICONINFORMATION
    );
    return true;
}
```

This works as expected with output like this:

[image]

Great. So I transplanted the code into a larger solution, again with the same small C# test project as described, and a larger existing C++ project where I need to include the same string passing functionality.

This time my C# code is very similar:

```
  [DllImport(@"my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern void ProcessOneFile([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str);

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessOneFile("Test2 String ☻我是美国人");
    }
```

and C++ code is basically the same too.

```
    __declspec(dllexport) cv::Mat __stdcall ProcessOneFile(wchar_t *FullFilePath) {
    MessageBoxW(
        NULL,
        FullFilePath ,
        L"Headervv",
        MB_ICONINFORMATION
    );
}
```

Yet I am getting this:

[image]

To test, I changed the C++ project from a DLL to an exe and called the ProcessOneFile function locally, using the following code from main() inside the same C++ file:

```
wchar_t *temp = L"C:/Z2C6BC1C克 - Copy.jpg";
ProcessOneFile(temp);
```

and I get :

[image]

So it seems the data is not surviving the transfer across the boundary from C# to C++.

Both solutions are running on the same PC, both compile in the same Visual Studio (2017) both c++ projects have Properties -> General -> Character Set set to "Use Unicode Character Set".

There must be something project related that is causing this, any help would be appreciated. I am not a C++ guy at all, I am trying to get the functionality I need from code on Github.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What's the significance of the `cv::Mat`?

Comment: @TripleAntigen If you write/pop the same message string in the C# code, what do you get? Also, check the text encoding of the `.cs` files in the two projects (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, BOM vs. no BOM etc).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I added a messagebox in the .cs file right before the call to ProcessOneFile and it appears correctly as in the first image.  Notepad++ reports them both as being UTF-8-BOM

Comment: @Flydog57 Nothing during these tests but I hoped to later pass a file name and return an image from the call after processing in the C++ dll.

Comment: I'd remove the `cv::Mat` from the return. Exporting a `class` is not advisable. I would also define your exported function as `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ProcessOneFile(wchar_t *FullFilePath)` to avoid name mangling issues. Also, what architecture are you building for, x86 or x64? What arch did your test project use?

Comment: Furthermore, the `OpenCV` `cv::Mat` is certainly not being exported (for obvious reasons). On a different note you really need to crank up your compiler warnings. If you're using `VS` set it to `W4`

Comment: @WBuck  OMG and just like that the problem is solved!! Thanks so much. If you want to turn that into an answer I will mark it as the solution. And thanks for the compiler warnings tip, I will do that. And it was for x64, for both C# and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First stop returning the `cv::Mat` from your function. Exporting a `class` has never been advisable. Furthermore the `OpenCV` `cv::Mat` is not being exported.

Also, to avoid name mangling prefix the function definition with `extern "C"`:

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ProcessOneFile(wchar_t *FullFilePath)`

Comment: Thanks so much, that solved my problem. I can start growing my hair back now.